# How to find out 2nd highest salary of employees?

Tags: sql, postgresql, derived-table

Created table named `geosalary` with columns `name`, `id`, and `salary`:

```
name   id  salary  
patrik  2  1000  
frank   2  2000  
chinmon 3  1300  
paddy   3  1700
```

I tried this below code to find 2nd highest salary:

```
SELECT salary
FROM (SELECT salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SALARY) AS DENSE_RANK FROM geosalary)
WHERE DENSE_RANK = 2;
```

However, getting this error message:

```
ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias  
SQL state: 42601  
Hint: For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.  
Character: 24
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: SELECT salary FROM (SELECT salary ,DENSE_RANK() as DENSE_RANK OVER(ORDER BY SALARY) AS DENSE_RANK FROM geosalary) as dontcare  WHERE DENSE_RANK=2;

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the error message is pretty clear: your sub-select needs an alias.

```
SELECT t.salary 
FROM (
      SELECT salary,
          DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY DESC) AS DENSE_RANK 
      FROM geosalary
      ) as t  --- this alias is missing
WHERE t.dense_rank = 2
```

Comment: I am trying leetcode question 
https://leetcode.com/problems/nth-highest-salary/submissions/

and it returns runtime error - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: @TusharS: this query can not result in that error ("subquery returns more than one row")

Answer (score 7):

The error message is pretty obvious: You need to supply an alias for the subquery.

Alternative query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT salary
FROM   geosalary
ORDER  BY salary DESC NULLS LAST
OFFSET 1
LIMIT  1;
```

This finds the "2nd highest salary" (1 row) as requested. Other queries find all employees with the 2nd highest salary (1-n rows).

I added `NULLS LAST`, as `null` values typically shouldn't rank first for this purpose. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

Comment: why this answer have lesser upvotes ? any specific reason ?

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede: Not sure. I added some explanation.

Comment: This is simplest solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT department_id, salary, RANK1 FROM (
    SELECT department_id,
           salary,
           DENSE_RANK ()
              OVER (PARTITION BY department_id ORDER BY SALARY DESC)
              AS rank1
    FROM employees) result  
WHERE rank1 = 3
```

This above query will get you the 3rd highest salary in the individual department. If you want regardless of the department, then just remove PARTITION BY department_id

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL engine doesn't know the "salary" column of which table you are using, that's why you need to use an alias to differentiate the two columns.
Try this:

```
SELECT salary
FROM (SELECT G.salary ,DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY G.SALARY) AS DENSE_RANK FROM geosalary G)
WHERE DENSE_RANK=2;
```

Comment: Read the error message again, your statement would still throw the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH salaries AS (SELECT salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SALARY) AS DENSE_RANK FROM geosalary)
SELECT * FROM salaries WHERE DENSE_RANK=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  level, max(salary)
from   geosalary
where   level=2
connect  by
prior   salary>salary
group  by  level;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of duplicates in salary column below query will give the right result:

```
WITH tmp_tbl AS
  (SELECT salary,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SALARY) AS DENSE_RANK
  FROM geosalary
  )
SELECT salary
FROM tmp_tbl
WHERE dense_rank =
  (SELECT MAX(dense_rank)-1 FROM tmp_tbl
  )
AND rownum=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is SQL standard**

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM   geosalary 
ORDER BY salary desc
OFFSET 1 ROW
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

**To calculate nth highest salary change offset value**

Answer (score 0):

select Max(es1.Salary) from EmployeeSalary es1
join EmployeeSalary es2 on es1.Salary<es2.Salary

Answer (score 0):

```
select top (1) es1.Salary from EmployeeSalary es1 
join EmployeeSalary es2 on es1.Salary < es2.Salary
order by Salary desc
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has a few answers—including one that has been validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM geosalary WHERE salary < ( SELECT MAX(salary) FROM geosalary )
```